# I'm trying to access http://localhost:5173/user/panel using React js Vite

Tags: reactjs, asp.net

I'm trying to access link: /user/panel but when i add /panel to the path by Route component as shown below it is giving me an error:

```
http://localhost:5173/user/src/main.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**The most confusing part is that there is src/main.jsx at the end of the url WHY!!!!!**

That's my App.jsx Routes

```
  <Router>
    <Routes>

      
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Welcome />} />   
      <Route exact path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route exact path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
      <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products />} />
      <Route element={<RestrictedRoute loggedIn={isLoggedIn} />}>
        <Route exact path="/8653-admin-2318" element={<Admin />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-questions" element={<AdminQuestions />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-users" element={<AdminUsers />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-ministry" element={<Ministry />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-organisation" element={<Organisation />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-support" element={<Support />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-algorithm" element={<Algorithm />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-legislation-add" element={<LegislationAdd />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-legislation-table" element={<LegislationTable />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-kosul-table" element={<KosulTable />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-sebep-table" element={<SebepTable />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-sart-table" element={<SartTable />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin-algorithm-condition-table" element={<AlgorithmConditions />} />
      </Route>


      <Route exact path="/admin-login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
      <Route exact path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
      <Route exact path="/payment" element={<PayPage />} />
```

ROUTE IS HERE!!!

```
      <Route exact path="/user/panel" element={<UserPanel/>} />
```

---

```
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

Im trying to make a url with tokens too as show but getting same error:

```
<Route exact path="/update-password/:tokenId/:userId" element={<UpdatePassword />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title></title>
    
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" /> -->
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="module" src="src/main.jsx"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

I've changed `src="src/main.jsx"` into `src="/src/main.jsx"` ADDED / before src